# php for loop on an object -zendform 2 forms

Tags: php, for-loop, zend-framework2

I am trying to retrieve data (a dependency) from a database and use the returned values to populate a zend form select element.

The final values should look like below:

```
$this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'name' => 'jobId',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'countryList',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '1'=>'USA',
                    '2'=> 'United Kingdom',
                    etc
                    '                
                    ),
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => '1' //set selected to '1'
            )
        ));
```

I have used doctrine2 to retrieve the values, i.e:

```
public function getOptionsForSelect()
{
    $entity = $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->getRepository('Workers\Entity\CountryList')
                    ->findAll();

    foreach ($entity as $entity)
           {
             echo $entity->country;
             echo $entity->id;

           }
}
```

The above gives me all the required values. I am however stuck on how to then place these values into an array such that once the `$this->getOptionsForSelect()` is placed in the form, it will immediately populate the values;

i.e.

```
  foreach ($entity as $entity)
  {

     $id =     $entity->id;
     $country= $entity->country;
     $data['data']      =  $id.'=>'.$country;

  }  
 return $data;
```

The final version of the form field will look like below:

```
$this->add(array(
            'name'    => 'countrylist',
            'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label'         => 'countrylist',
                'value_options' => $this->getOptionsForSelect(),
                'empty_option'  => '--- please choose ---'
            )
        ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ObjectSelect/EntitySelect in DoctrineModule for ZF2 which might simplify this - https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md

You don't need your own getOptionsForSelect(), because doctrine can handle that already.

Comment: hi user1786423. thank for pointing it out to me. i will try it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could implement your `getOptionsForSelect` like so:

```
public function getOptionsForSelect()
{
    $entity = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('Workers\Entity\CountryList')
        ->findAll();
    $options = array();
    foreach ($entity as $entity) {
         $options[$entity->id] = $entity->country;
    }
    return $options;
}
```

I haven't worked with doctrine, but I'd expect it to have some method to extract data as an array, or at least that I'd be possible to pass it to some serialized object to do that.

Comment: Hello guessimtoolate. thank you for your help; you helped me a lot ot understand how to control the for loop